# using jquery read values from a json file

Tags: jquery

Using jquery I am trying to read values from a json file and populate in a dropdown.

For that I am doing the following
but `undefined` value is getting in dropdown.
What's wrong with my code?
json file

```
   {
      "VMs":[
        {
          "ID":"VM-WIN7-64",
          "OS":"Windows 7",
          "FLAVOUR":"VM-IE8-001-preq",
          "ADAPTER":"Win 9"
        }
      ],
      "Paths":{
        "VM-WIN7-64":"C:\\VirtualMachines\\Win7_X64_VM-001\\Win7_X64_VM-001.vmx"
      }
    }
```

code

```
function getOsNames() {
 $.getJSON('/json/data.json', function(data) 
    {
var html = '';
        $.each(data,function(val,i)
        {
alert(val);
html += '<option value="' + val.OS + '">' + val.OS + '</option>';
        });
     $('#op').html(html);     

    });

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to loop through `data.VMs` as it is having the OS property

```
function getOsNames() {
    $.getJSON('/json/data.json', function (data) {
        var html = '';
        $.each(data.VMs, function (i, val) {
            html += '<option value="' + val.OS + '">' + val.OS + '</option>';
        });
        $('#op').html(html);
    });
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/PK9s6/)

Comment: getting undefined data in place of os

Comment: @Sush the each callback parameter order is swapped

Comment: you have grab only one value in select menu...if we need to add all value then what changes we need to do

Comment: in fiddle ur using static data how can i read from a josn file

Comment: @Sush it is the same... did you check the above answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use for loop :

```
for(var i=0;i<data.VMs.length;i++)
{
   html += '<option value="' + data.VMs[i].OS + '">' + data[i].VMs[i].OS + '</option>';
}
$('#op').html(html);
```

This will solve your problem